# ViewStub in MotionLayout stays Invisible

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

*I have an existing ConstraintLayout with some views and a ViewStub.
I converted it to MotionLayout but the ViewStub won't appear.*

I have the following layout :

```
<MotionLayout app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene">
    <Button id="button01"/>
    <ViewStub id="stub" inflatedId="merger"/>
</MotionLayout>
```

For the given Motion scene :

```
<MotionScene>
    <Transition
      app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
      app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
        <OnClick app:clickAction="toggle" app:targetId="button"/>            
    </Transition>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/button" ...>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/button" ...>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

In my activity I set the visibility of the ViewStub to View.VISIBLE.
It works when I use a ConstraintLayout or a MotionLayout without motionscene, meaning, the view stub is correctly replaced by its content and all is visible.
**When I use a motion scene, the animation of the button plays correctly but the inflated layout of the ViewStub is invisible** (not gone i guess cause I can see it in the layout inspector).

I tried using the property

> app:visibilityMode="ignore"

without success

Is it because MotionLayout is still in development or did I miss something ? (Another wrap_content issue ?).

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Same issue here!

Answer (score 0):

A few notes. First, in order for a viewStub to appear, it must be inflated, not just the visibility set. So make sure you are calling `stub.inflate()` somewhere in your code.

Also, any views that you wish to appear in your MotionLayout should be defined with constraints in the motionScene. So if you expect to have an inflated view, that inflated view should be in the constraints. Something like this:

```
<MotionScene>
<Transition
  app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
  app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end">
    <OnClick app:clickAction="toggle" app:targetId="button"/>            
</Transition>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/button" ...>
    <Constraint android:id="@id/merger" ...>
</ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/button" ...>
    <Constraint android:id="@id/merger" ...>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Try that and let me know how it goes!